# Twitter Application distribution

Tags: api, twitter, wordpress

I am fairly new to this and I do apologise if this is a very basic set of questions. What I would like to know is:

1. I have created an app which I use a custom WordPress plugin to post tweets from my blog. However I want to release the WordPress plugin and would like people to be able to use my application. I am worried though, about giving out code that has all my access tokens and keys. How would I be able to release the plugin that uses my application to other users to post their posts to twitter?
2. Are there limits in place for my application to send tweets to Twitter or does it go per user?

Thank you in advance for any help. Much appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider [ThinkUp's approach](https://github.com/ginatrapani/ThinkUp/wiki/Configuration%3a-Twitter). It requires users to register their own application with Twitter so that they have their own Twitter API consumer key and secret, and any API limits (or potential abuses) are tied only to their installation of the plugin.